# Getting specific row item from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datatable

I've got a datatable. Lets call it dt. It has three columns. *id, link_id and value.* I'm using a for each loop to loop through each result in the datatable.

```
For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Try
        'do whatever
    Catch Ex As Exception
    End Try
```

In my *do whatever* bit, how would I grab just the **value** of the current row and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Also via Row(colIndex)

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz you would have to substitute `Row.Item["COLUMN_NAME"]` with `Row.Item("COLUMN_NAME")` for VB

Comment: You may access values at **do whatever** with `Row.Item("COLUMN_NAME")` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for further details) - thx @joehanna for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following.

```
For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Try
               var linkId = row("link_id")
            Catch Ex As Exception
            End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using a generic `DataTable`:

```
For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows
  Try
    'Show all 3 fields/columns
    Console.WriteLine Row.Item(0) & " - " & Row.Item(1) & " - " & Row.Item(2) 
  Catch Ex As Exception
  End Try
Next
```

Try this if you are using a strongly-typed `DataTable`:

```
For Each Row As StronglyTypedDataRow In dt.Rows
  Try
    'Show all 3 fields/columns
    Console.WriteLine Row.id & " - " & Row.link_id  & " - " & Row.Value 
  Catch Ex As Exception
  End Try
Next
```